# Add captions to ffmpeg video slideshow

Tags: ffmpeg, caption

I would like to create a video slideshow using ffmpeg as described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) or similarly.

I would like to add an annotation caption of text for each image. This isn't contained in the image metadata but could be taken from a spreadsheet or text file.

Is this possible? Any tips on how I might go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create video from a set of images, and then add hardsubs to it: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo.